# How to validate the access_token generated by onelogin using API

Tags: oauth-2.0, onelogin

If I can perform authentication using oAuth2 using onelogin, can I also validate the same token using REST API's instead of accessing the the onelogin resources ?

I ask this question because for Google we can validate it using JWK keys, and other tokens ca be validated by the server keys. If that is not possible then at-least we should be having some REST API that could validate the token when passed. Does onelogin support any of these use-cases ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out our OIDC support (https://developers.onelogin.com/openid-connect) as this basically allows for Authenticating users via JWT/JWK tokens